# How to configure slf4j-android?

Tags: android, slf4j

I use slf4j-android in my Android application.
The doc says if I write `log.trace` then it's the almost the same as I write `Log.v`.
But the default logging level seems to be INFO, and logcat shows only `log.info` and above, and I can't see how can I change the defaults.

1) How can I configure slf4j-android

2) If I can't: are there any other slf4j implementations for Android, more configurable

Comment: Unless you've found some faults with Android's logging library, then there's no point in including external logging library as this just increases the size of your app unnecessarily.

Comment: use my library (ILog) http://moshx.com/ilog-v0-1-is-here/

Comment: android's logging library is cumbersome to use

Comment: There was something wrong with the phone, it just never printed anything below INFO either with standard Log.d or any other way I tried. Sony Xperia E4.

Comment: @ChuongPham If your Android app uses a Java library then that library can't use Android logging, hence slf4j-android

Answer (score 2):

For example if your tag is `MyClass` type in command line

`adb shell setprop log.tag.MyClass DEBUG`

The way I found is this procedure
Find logger slf4j-android source [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-android/src/main/java/org/slf4j/impl/AndroidLoggerAdapter.java)

You should see that all methods are preceded by if (isLoggable(...)) that in turn call android.util.Log isLoggable which can be found on [opengrok](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/Log.java#195)

The description of this method explains how to set a proper property.

Note that slf4j-android will rename longer tags i.e. `WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver` will be changed to sth like `*directBroadcastReceiver`.
As far as I know you cannot use * in setprop calls so you need to manage your tags carefully.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain, but I won't give up on `slf4j`. This is what I ended up doing:

1. In my source code, I instantiate a logger per activity:

```java
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final Logger LOGGER = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
    ...
}
```

2. In the project root, I place a shell script for setting the logging level of all activities in one go:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Add as many lines as needed to set the logging for 
# all the activities in your app
adb shell setprop log.tag.MyActivity "$1"
```

3. Then, whenever I need to set the logging level for a session, I switch to the `Terminal` view in `Android Studio` and just run the script:

```sh
$ sh adb-setloglevel VERBOSE
```